# What's the default serif font in firefox?

Tags: firefox, fonts, browser

I'm trying to come up with a solid font stack that incorporates fonts typically found on an ubuntu install.

font-family=serif looks great, but for obvious reasons, this isn't appropriate for other operating systems.

What font does "serif" resolve to in the default install? I'm on firefox 6. Edit->Preferences->Content->Fonts & Colors/Advanced...->Serif is set to "serif" so it seems like it's using whatever ubuntu defines as the "serif" font. How can I tell what that is?

I'm on 11.04 (from a fresh install)

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The list is system dependent. To the get the list on your computer use [fc-match](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/fc-match.1.html) and specify a font name to match against. The `-s` option gives a sorted list.

Here's the output from a 12.04 TLS Server listing serif, sans-serif, and monospace font styles to be thorough:

```
user@server:~$ fc-match -s serif
DejaVuSerif.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Book"
DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Bold"
n021003l.pfb: "Nimbus Roman No9 L" "Regular"
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"
s050000l.pfb: "Standard Symbols L" "Regular"
DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold"
DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Bold"

user@server:~$ fc-match -s sans-serif
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold"
n019003l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular"
DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"
DejaVuSerif.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Book"
s050000l.pfb: "Standard Symbols L" "Regular"
DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Bold"
DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Bold"

user@server:~$ fc-match -s mono
DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"
DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Bold"
n022003l.pfb: "Nimbus Mono L" "Regular"
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
DejaVuSerif.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Book"
s050000l.pfb: "Standard Symbols L" "Regular"
DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold"
DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Bold"
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it will actually use the font called "Serif", which is an unbranded version of Bitstream Vera Serif. The sans-serif default I likewise understand to be "Sans", an unbranded version of Bitstream Vera Sans. (And by now you've perhaps figured out that "Monospace" is really Bitstream Vera Sans Mono . . . .)

EDIT: ttf-bitstream-vera is in universe in the latest few releases of Ubuntu. In light of this, I believe that belacqua is correct in judging the font used ultimately to be of the DejaVu family (which is a rebranded Bitstream Vera with better international character support, I believe). The font used is still Serif (the same goes for Sans and Monospace), but this links to DejaVu rather than Bitstream Vera.

Answer (score 2):

On my 11.04 system with firefox 6.0 and on my 11.10 beta system with firefox 7.0, the only serif font I see used is this one:

`/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf`

This comes from the `ttf-dejavu` package, which appears to be installed by default on 11.04 and 11.10:

> Description: Metapackage to pull in ttf-dejavu-core and
>   ttf-dejavu-extra  DejaVu provides an expanded version of the Vera font
>   family aiming for  quality and broader Unicode coverage while
>   retaining the original Vera  style. DejaVu currently works towards
>   conformance with the Multilingual  European Standards (MES-1 and
>   MES-2) for Unicode coverage. The DejaVu  fonts provide serif, sans and
>   monospaced variants.
>   
>   .
>   Use this package if you want all DejaVu variants.
>   .
>   DejaVu fonts are intended for use on low-resolution devices (mainly
>   computer screens) but can be used in printing as well.

Comment: Downvoted?  If there is invalid info here, please let me know.